# CRM 2011 - JScript not working in one organisation but is in another

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I have deployed a solution from my development area to two other separate servers/organisations. In this solution I am using some scripts on an entity form as soon as they load. In my development area and one of the others everything seems to work fine but in the other one i get an error as soon as i open the form saying "Error loading resource: syntax error". The error message relates to  a function i am calling from another script from my on load script.

So i'm not sure if it is a coding error on my part as it does work in two of the CRM systems. But is there any settings or configuration that could affect it? Or an easy way to check what the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i may have found an answer to this, it appears that the code is not picking up the CRM system's server and organisation name correctly for some reason on this instance. So i'm going to check through the code to see why this is

Comment: Hello jimminybob, i'm facing a problem something similar to yours. I have imported all my javascripts from one organisation to other and no java scripts are working in imported organization. What may be the problem. The server name and organization name all are same.

Comment: Are there any differences between the two servers and organisations? One thing I've found in the past is that if one is on a different version to the other then sometimes javascript code doesn't work as expected. Also is there any error with them or are they just not doing anything?